# Is this neon light display real or fake? how does it work?

Tags: light, display, neon

Is this neon light display real or fake? if real, then how does it work?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlcywgEMuGI

Comment: Please edit your question or it will deleted. It contains barely more than a link which makes the whole question useless in case the video is deleted from YT one day. Furthermore, it consists of more than one question. You do not seem to have done some research on your own before.

Comment: Delete it i couldnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not neon. There are LEDs with different colors inside the white tubing.
The programming makes it look nice.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like programmable LEDs inside the tubes, such as this kind of thing https://www.adafruit.com/product/1460?length=1